# Reload page after selected row in datatable JSF + PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm trying on button click show up selected row of a datatable. I'm using tag `rendered` to show/hide this button, but it is rendered only when the page is reloaded. For this reason I want that when I selected row, the page is reloaded and tag rendered is executed again.

Function `conv` return a boolean value, depending of if button should show up or not.

Any idea how to do it?

```
<p:dataTable id="singleDT" var="inform" value="#{testBean.searchInform}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{testBean.selectedInform}" rowKey={inform.id}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Single with Row Click
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{inform.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{inform.year}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{inform.brand}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{inform.color}" />
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton for="singleDT" process="singleDT" update=":form:informeDetail" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Convert" action="#{testBean.Convert}" rendered="#{testBean.conv}"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: do you know that there is an ajax event for selected row

Answer (score 0):

When `rendered` is `false` the HTML document will not contain the given component, thus it cannot refresh it.

You should place your `<p:commandButton>` inside another JSF component, and rerender that enclosing component instead.